# Aggregate patio resurfacing - what are my best options?

Tags: patio, diy-vs-pro, resurfacing

I am looking for options to repair or cover a poorly maintained, exposed aggregate patio. Its approximately 20'x23', with no water issues.

After seeking quotes on resurfacing, I've decided isn't in my budget. I've considered either covering with wood decking or slab rock.

Can anyone tell me if this is even worth considering, or should I bite the bullet and have it professionally resurfaced?